# Why is Python V3.3 installed by default on Xubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, application-development, python

I am running Xubuntu 13.10, 64 bit.

`python --version` outputs `Python 2.7.5+` which is normal since python 2.7 is installed by default on all Linux distros.

But when I go to Software center -> and click on the installed tab -> development tools. I see python IDE version 3.3.

Is it installed by default on all Ubuntu/Xubuntu 13.10? And if so, why?

Comment: People are starting to use Python 3 for development.. So, yeah, it should be installed. You may have installed a program that uses python 3..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Python 2 and Python 3 are installed by default on Ubuntu (and derivatives).

Python 3 is the newer version of it and applications are being updated to work with it, however many programs still use 2 (for various reasons)

The default `python` program links to Python 2 for compatibility reasons,  2 is incompatible with 3.

To use Python 3, you should use `python3` instead.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.4
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.4
$ python3 --version
Python 3.3.1
```

Comment: the languages are not incompatible, there are simply some incompatible **features** between 2 and 3. It is quite easy to write code that works with both versions.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.x and Python 3.x are different languages. They are both installed by default in Ubuntu 13.10. Some applications require 2.7.x and some require 3.x.